# parse call function in background messes up order sequence

Tags: ios, objective-c, multithreading, parse-platform, objective-c-blocks

I need to retrieve a couple of `NSDicionaries` that are compared against an id.

First, I'm calling a `NSArray` with these id's in them. I'm looping over them to see get the details of that id, and with that i'm calling another pfcloud function. Up until this point, all goes well. However, when I'm logging the payment details of the payment id's, the order sequence is is in a different order than the array I putted it in.

```
for(__block NSString *paymentId in success){
   [self getPaymentDetails:paymentId];
}
```

So for instance: `success = @[@"1",@"2",@"3"]`

the method `getPaymentDetails` will log me`@[@"details about 1", @"details about 3", @"details about 2"]`

However, I need them to be in the exact same order.
This is my getPaymentDetails code:

```
-(void)getPaymentDetails:(NSString *)paymentId{
PFUser *currentUser = [PFUser currentUser];
  [PFCloud callFunctionInBackground:@"getpaymentdetails"
                     withParameters:@{@"objectid": paymentId, @"userid": currentUser.objectId}
                              block:^(NSDictionary *success, NSError *error) {
                                if(success){
                              NSDictionary *payment = success;
                              NSString *amount = [payment objectForKey:@"amount"];
                              if (![amount isKindOfClass:[NSNull class]]) {
                                [self.amountArray addObject:amount];
                              }
                              else {
                                [self.amountArray addObject:@""];
                              }

                              NSString *from = [payment objectForKey:@"from"];
                              if (![from isKindOfClass:[NSNull class]]) {
                                [self.fromArray addObject:from];
                              }
                              else {
                                [self.fromArray addObject:@""];
                              }

                            } else{
                              NSLog(@"Error logged getpaymentdetails: %@", error);
                            }

                          }]; 
}
```

The values stored in the `amountArray` for instance, do not match the index of the `paymentId`
How come and how do I solve this?

Comment: `__block` is useless there. That `paymentId` is not used in a block

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may be simpler to just move the whole for loop into the background and then call the Parse function synchronously

```
dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0);
dispatch_group_t group = dispatch_group_create();


dispatch_group_async(group,queue, ^{

    for(__block NSString *paymentId in success){
       [self getPaymentDetails:paymentId];
    }

});

dispatch_group_wait(group, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER);

// Release the group when it is no longer needed.
dispatch_release(group);
```

Then in your `getPaymentDetails` you would call `callFunction:withParameters:error:` instead of `callFunctionInBackground:withParameters:`

This isn't an ideal solution however, as you are eliminating concurrency and so it will take longer to execute.

A better solution is to deal with the fact that the array is unordered at the conclusion of the loop and sort it once all of the data has been retrieved

Answer (score 0):

The request `callFunctionInBackground` will do is executed asynchronously and there is no guarantee that the first call you make in your loop will finish first. This is not really related to Parse itself, that is just the nature of how this is done. You may end up with the same order by coincidence or a completely random one each time you execute this code.

If you want the order to stay the same, either pass in all IDs to your Cloud Function and update your Cloud Function to handle it or always wait for one call to finish, add the result to your array and then get the details with the next ID (basically a queue).

Comment: Thanks Bjorn! How do I create such a queue?

Comment: That would be out of scope in a comment thread and not really what the core of your original question was, however here is a basic approach: You have an array with the IDs you would like to get the details from, you then take the first one, do whatever you need to do to get the details, and when you are done you remove that ID from your queue array, check if there are more IDs, if not you are done, if yes you call the code that fetches the details again. Then you repeat that until the queue (your array) is empty.

Comment: Thanks, I think that's the basic principle of a queue btw, but could you maybe point me to some method or doc that relates to that? I don't know how to do this since I've never did this.